# Trap delete key

Tags: excel, vba

My problem is fairly trivial: I need to apply logic to the delete button in Excel. In [a related question I asked for means to clear cells in a pivot table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7977867/excel-clear-cells-in-an-pivot-table), and realising now that this might not be the right approach, this is yet another alternative I'm considering. Unfortunately, I admittedly have little experience with Visual Basic, and this task is proving such a challenge (quite surprisingly).

Is it possible to trap (as in listen to) the delete-key in Excel and trigger a subroutine in VBA when pressed?

I'd appreciate all kind of input! Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

You case use `Application.Onkey` to assign code to keys

If you 
(1) add this code to a sheet module that contains your pivottable (right-click your sheet tab, View Code and past the code below)

This code activates and then de-activates the intercept when the user enters then leaves this particular sheet:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
Application.OnKey "{DELETE}", "Intercept"
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Deactivate()
Application.OnKey "{DELETE}"
End Sub
```

(2) add this code to a regular module

```
Sub Intercept()
MsgBox "user just pressed delete"
End Sub
```

then delete on that sheet will be trapped and the user given a message

Comment: note that it will cancel the normal behavior of the key (+1 though :))

Comment: Thanks :). I was wondering as per the comment from JMax if this would be enough, or if you wanted further code in the VBA routine to actually run a delete (on range, chart, object) etc. I took the minimalist - and easiest approach :) - to the question to see if this would be ok as is.

Comment: Yes, in this case it's perfect. I don't want the default delete operation to run.