# Cannot run macro to trap delete key

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to trap the DEL key on an EXCEL chart using VBA to prevent users from deleting chart series manually.  I adapted the code from this article

[Trap delete key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7981055/trap-delete-key)

as follows:

```
Private Sub Chart_Activate()
    Application.OnKey "{DELETE}", "Intercept_DelKey"
End Sub

Private Sub Chart_Deactivate()
    Application.OnKey "{DELETE}"
End Sub

Sub Intercept_DelKey()
    MsgBox "user just pressed delete"
End Sub
```

However when I press the DEL key I get this error

> Cannot run the macros ***.xlsm!Intercept_DelKey.  The macro may not be
>   available in this workbook or all macros may be disabled.

Other macros are running so the problem is presumably one of scope?  I tried declaring the macro as

```
Public Sub Intercept_DelKey()
```

but get the same issue.  All suggestions welcome - thanks!

Comment: Put the macro in a normal module, not the sheet module.

Comment: Have you tried renaming `Intercept_DelKey()` to `InterceptDelKey()`. It should  not have an influence, but the `_` (Underscore) in Function names in VBA is used to identify an Interface.

Comment: @Rory to extend on this, put only the macro `Intercept_DelKey()` in a public module. The `Private Sub Chart_Activate()` `Private Sub Chart_Deactivate()` should stay in the code-behind of the Chart.

Comment: @L8n the other two are events, not macros. :)

Comment: @Rory all of them are Procedures, some invoked by an Event, some by calling them explicitly. Most computer instruction are macros in some way or another (by definition a macro maps a modified input to an output...) The name "Macro" for VBA-Procedures is a bit of a unlucky choice anyway since it kind of denigrates the capabilities of VBA...

Comment: Rory - that worked.  Easy when you how how  but impossible when you don't - thanks!